# unable to read array fields using trino written by flink with parquet-mr 1.12.3 , how can i configure the parquet-mr version to be used in trino?

Tags: hive, apache-flink, parquet, trino

I am trying to run a simple query:

```
select *
from table
where date_key = '2023-03-05'
limit 10
```

and im getting the following error:

```
Trino Error
trino error: class org.apache.parquet.io.PrimitiveColumnIO cannot be cast to class 
org.apache.parquet.io.GroupColumnIO (org.apache.parquet.io.PrimitiveColumnIO and 
org.apache.parquet.io.GroupColumnIO are in unnamed module of loader 
io.trino.server.PluginClassLoader @259fe541)
```

i narrowed down to array fields, because i changed the query, and selecting other datatypes work fine, and when selecting a single array field it gets the same error.

I believe its a parquet-mr version setup. The team maintaining the trino cluster is running trino 378. But I couldnt figure out from the trino release notes (https://trino.io/docs/current/release) if this is upgraded by trino, or if there is a hive connector config to set which parquet-mr library version to use.

The parquet files are written by a flink app using parquet-mr 1.12.3 that got released after trino 378 (https://parquet.apache.org/blog/2022/05/26/1.12.3/). This is why my first assumption is a version mismatch.

It would be great to know if someone knows how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the same mistake happens for columns of type `ARRAY <STRING>` after updating from engine version 2 to version 3 in Amazon Athena.

Comment: any update on this? facing the same issue...